# CSS elements overlaping but i want one under another

Tags: html, css

I'm building a web site but I'm relatively new to CSS and i have a problem with positioning of elements on it. I want to have a header where there will be a menu with options for different parts of site, content part where there will be content and footer with links on social media. I've made the header part with menu but content keeps overlaping with it, more precisely it's under menu bar. If you can help me I'll be really grateful.

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Lato';
}
a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: white;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 96px;
}

.footer-social {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.footer-social ul {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.footer-social li {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Photos">Photos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Events">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            Text
        </div>

        <div class="footer-social">
             <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
                 <img src='http://www.womenactionmedia.org/cms/assets/themes/crate/images/social/facebook.png' />
             </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I've made a jsfiddle but I don't see problem with your code : https://jsfiddle.net/4cj1evjp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with below code it may help you

```css
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
  background : #ddd;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-weight: 100;
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none !important;
            color: white;
        }
        .menu{
        background : black;
        }
        .menu ul li{
         display : inline-block;
         padding : 8px;
        }
        
        .menu ul li:hover, a:hover{
         background : white;
         color : black;
        }
        .container {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .content {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 96px;
        }

        .footer-social {
            float: right;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .footer-social ul {
            float: right;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .footer-social li {
            float: right;
            list-style: none;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#Home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#Photos">Photos</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#Events">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    Text
  </div>

  <div class="footer-social">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
      <img src='http://www.womenactionmedia.org/cms/assets/themes/crate/images/social/facebook.png' />
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you are always weclom :)